# What are the areas of origin of the Hand?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-defenders-2017

On *The Defenders*, we learn that the Hand consists of

> five individuals from various parts of the world who were banished from K’un Lun.

So far as I can tell:

- Madame Gao is originally from China.
- Murakami is originally from Japan.
- Sowande is originally from Africa, but I didn’t catch any mention of which country.

Is there any evidence or information on what countries or regions they hail from? Where are Bakuto and Alexandra from? And do we know anything more specific about Sowande?

Comment: given how long ago this supposedly happened modern-day "country" boundaries almost certainly didn't exist

Comment: @Kutulu - True.

Comment: @KutuluMike - However, what I meant was that Madame Gao, for example, came from an area that is now part of China. So, for example, did Alexandra come from ancient Greece? What’s now Britain? Germany?

Comment: Madame Gao is probably not from China in any period. She strongly hints that she's from one of the Heavens.

Comment: @Paul - I thought she was just referencing that she was from K’un-L’un (but had presumably lived in China before that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The show never really explains *where* these five fingers of the Hand come from, but they do drop a very small number of clues. The ones you already got include:

- Gao, obviously, is from China. Besides her name and ethnicity being obvious, and the fact that she speaks Chinese, she talks about dragons in her homeland. Dragons are very strongly associated with ancient China
- Murukami is from Japan, based mostly on his name and ethnicity, and that he speaks Japanese.
- Sowande is from Africa. Since the events supposedly happened thousands of years ago, the modern country borders likely did not exist, so mostly likely he was part of a migratory African tribe.

On top of that:

- Bakuto is referred to as “the assistance coming from South America”, so it seems likely that he’s from South America. This would again fit with his ethnicity (the actor is Puerto Rican). The name, unfortunately, seems Japanese in origin, so it’s likely not his original name.
- Alexandra (also, likely not her real name) is caucasian. It’s unlikely she is from the Americas, so most likely she comes from somewhere in western Europe. The biggest clue we get to her identity is, early in the show, she compliments the chef at a restaurant by saying their food was “even better than they made it in Constantinople”. Unfortunately, that was the name of the city up into nearly the 20th century (long after the Hand arrived in New York), but if that’s somewhere she’s intimately familiar with, it might indicate that she came from the area around Greece or Turkey. That would also fit well with her chosen name.

Comment: If Alexandra is from the eastern Mediterranean, how about Alexandria in Egypt?

Comment: There is a large Japanese population in Brazil. That may explain Bakuto's name

Comment: Doesn't it imply she knew Brahms and Mozart?